# Optimization between 2 dependent variables

Tags: optimization, data-analysis, linear-programming

I couldn't find a solution nowhere, so I'm asking here. Hope someone knows how to guide me thru.

So, I'm not quite sure if this is a optimization problem (if anyone know what kind of problem is this, let me know), but I need to find the quantity of clients that each attendant has to have so that each has the same amount of orders. I don't know if there is a function or a regression that could be made of this.

Column A has the clients name. Column B has the "difficulty" that each client is to assist - that is, "1" is normal difficulty, "2" is double the normal difficulty and so on - meaning that the orders of this clients will be multiplied by his difficulty. Column C has a spec that only attendant Y can assist. Column D has the quantity of orders that each client requested. And finally column E is the account attendant.

| CLIENT | ATTENTION | SPEC | ORDERS | ATTENDANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 3 | 0 | 6 | y |
| a2 | 3 | 0 | 7 | x |
| a3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | y |
| a4 | 1 | 0 | 9 | y |
| a5 | 2 | 0 | 6 | y |
| a6 | 1 | 0 | 7 | y |
| a7 | 3 | 0 | 2 | y |
| a8 | 3 | 0 | 9 | x |
| a9 | 3 | 0 | 9 | y |
| a10 | 2 | 1 | 8 | y |
| a11 | 2 | 0 | 8 | x |
| a12 | 2 | 0 | 9 | y |
| a13 | 1 | 1 | 2 | y |
| a14 | 2 | 0 | 4 | x |
| a15 | 3 | 0 | 10 | y |
| a16 | 2 | 0 | 9 | x |
| a17 | 2 | 0 | 8 | y |
| a18 | 1 | 1 | 5 | y |
| a19 | 3 | 0 | 8 | x |
| a20 | 1 | 1 | 3 | y |
| a21 | 2 | 0 | 10 | x |
| a22 | 2 | 0 | 6 | x |

Summary tables:

| ATTENDANT | TOTAL ORDERS |
| --- | --- |
| x | 61 |
| y | 84 |

| ATTENDANT | TOTAL CLIENTS |
| --- | --- |
| x | 8 |
| y | 14 |

| ATTENDANT | TOTAL ORDERS |
| --- | --- |
| x | 61 |
| y | 84 |
| y (spec 0) | 66 |
| y (spec 1) | 18 |

Comment: This is an "Assignment Problem" that can be attacked with Integer Linear Programming (ILP).  You can use `pulp`, `pyomo`, or `or-tools` to attack this and set up decision variables for which tasks are assigned to which attendant

Comment: Are you trying to balance the raw # of orders or balance the sum product of order * difficulty?  For example, does Y get 6 units from customer a1 or does Y get 18 units?

Comment: @AirSquid in trying to balance order * difficulty, I had to give some clients an abstract quoeficient to make it more realistic. Order column is the raw # tho, yet to be multiplied. I'm looking to balance order * diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a linear program that solves this.  Fun problem!  This uses the `pyomo` environment and the separately installed `glpk` solver.  Result:  It's a tie!  X and Y don't need to haggle!  ;)

#### Code:

```
# client assignment

import csv
from collections import namedtuple
import pyomo.environ as pyo

data_file = 'data.csv'

Record = namedtuple('Record', ['attention', 'spec', 'orders'])

records = {}
with open(data_file, 'r') as src:
    src.readline()  # burn header row
    reader = csv.reader(src, skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        record = Record(int(line[1]), int(line[2]), int(line[3]))
        records[line[0]] = record

#print(records)

# set up the ILP

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# SETS

m.C = pyo.Set(initialize=records.keys())  # the set of clients
m.A = pyo.Set(initialize=['X', 'Y'])      # the set of attendants

# PARAMETERS

m.attention  = pyo.Param(m.C, initialize={c: r.attention for (c, r) in records.items()})
m.y_required = pyo.Param(m.C, initialize={c: r.spec for (c, r) in records.items()})
m.orders     = pyo.Param(m.C, initialize={c: r.orders for (c, r) in records.items()})

# VARIABLES

m.assign = pyo.Var(m.A, m.C, domain=pyo.Binary)   # 1: assign attendant a to client c
m.work_delta = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)   # the abs(work difference)

# OBJECTIVE

# minimize the work delta...
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=m.work_delta)

# CONSTRAINTS

# each client must be serviced once and only once
def service(m, c):
    return sum(m.assign[a, c] for a in m.A) == 1
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(m.C, rule=service)

# y-specific customers must be serviced by attendant y, and optionally if not reqd.
def y_serves(m, c):
    return m.assign['Y', c] >= m.y_required[c]
m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(m.C, rule=y_serves)

# some convenience expressions to capture work...
m.y_work = sum(m.attention[c] * m.orders[c] * m.assign['Y', c] for c in m.C)
m.x_work = sum(m.attention[c] * m.orders[c] * m.assign['X', c] for c in m.C)

# capture the ABS(y_work - x_work) with 2 constraints
m.C3a = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.work_delta >= m.y_work - m.x_work)
m.C3b = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.work_delta >= m.x_work - m.y_work)

# check the model
#m.pprint()

# SOLVE
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
res = solver.solve(m)
# ensure the result is optimal
status = res.Solver()['Termination condition'].value
assert(status == 'optimal', f'error occurred, status: {status}.  Check model!')

print(res)

print(f'x work: {pyo.value(m.x_work)} units')
print(f'y work: {pyo.value(m.y_work)} units')

# list assignments
for c in m.C:
    for a in m.A:
        if pyo.value(m.assign[a, c]):
            print(f'Assign {a} to customer {c}')
```

#### Output:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 0.0
  Upper bound: 0.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 47
  Number of variables: 46
  Number of nonzeros: 157
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 53
      Number of created subproblems: 53
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.008551836013793945
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

x work: 158.0 units
y work: 158.0 units
Assign Y to customer a1
Assign Y to customer a2
Assign X to customer a3
Assign Y to customer a4
Assign Y to customer a5
Assign Y to customer a6
Assign Y to customer a7
Assign Y to customer a8
Assign X to customer a9
Assign Y to customer a10
Assign X to customer a11
Assign X to customer a12
Assign Y to customer a13
Assign X to customer a14
Assign X to customer a15
Assign X to customer a16
Assign X to customer a17
Assign Y to customer a18
Assign X to customer a19
Assign Y to customer a20
Assign Y to customer a21
Assign Y to customer a22
[Finished in 588ms]
```

#### In Excel Solver

Note:  in the solver options, be sure to de-select "ignore integer constraints"

This seems to work OK.  The green shaded areas are "locked" to Y and not in the solver's control.

I'm always suspicious of the solver in Excel, so check everything!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't really use Python tho, do you think it is possible to do something similar using Excel or VBA?

Comment: The Excel solver isn’t that great, but I think it is probably capable of this.  I don’t think any VBA required.  Just set up the columns nearly as you have, multiply the work * number of jobs, and multiply by a binary column for both X and Y, put in a row-sum over those two columns, make it =1.  I believe solver has support for binary variables…

Comment: I'm not familiar with this level of math, but if I got it right, work * # of jobs = Orders * Attention? If so, I could make 2 new columns for X and Y so that each line shows the product of each attendant's clients. Then, I didn't get how to multiply then by a binary column, should I make 2 new more columns (one for X and one for Y) and fill them with what exactly? Which line will be 1 or 0?

Comment: added a screenshot of Excel solver.  Has same solution, so I think it is OK.  You should be able to infer the cell contents, and I added some "notes" to column tops.

Comment: Sir, you are my hero, thank you a lot!